# How to fill transparent area left by resize in Gimp 2.8

Tags: canvas, resize, transparent, fill, gimp

when I do a canvas resize of an image, it leaves a new transparent area. I would like to fill that area with a color but Gimp 2.8 won't allow me to select it to fill it. I must be missing a step. Please help.

Comment: You need to resize the layer, or add a new layer with the new size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018007/resize-layer-to-fit-canvas-gimp?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Command in menu `Image -> Flatten Image` will fill transparent area with current background color selection (as hinted by pop-up help when you select it - `"... remove transparency"`), making exactly what you asked in one simple step (tested in Gimp 2.8).

Answer (score 10):

You cannot fill outside the boundaries of the layer. If initially your layer is the size of the canvas and you scale it down, it will be smaller than the canvas so there are areas around it that you won't be able to fill. Two solutions:

1. Add a canvas-size layer below it and paint that layer
2. Use *Layer>Layer to image size* to enlarge the layer so that it fills the canvas
3. (*) Use *Image>Fit canvas to layers* to shrink the canvas around the layer so the fill isn't needed.

(*) The Spanish Inquisition made me do it.

Comment: this answer explains *why* gimp is behaving this way, so it's the best one -- thanks